# Mysql Syntax Error when running as prepared statment

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, pdo

I've this stored procedure in which I am using a prepared statment to perform two queries.Here's the procedure.

```
SET @uid    = puserid;
SET @rangee = plimit * 50;
SET @post = 'post';

PREPARE STMT FROM 
'
SELECT  notifications.postid,victims.victimid,friends.friendsname,notificationrecievers.status 

FROM friends,victims,notifications,notificationrecievers

WHERE victims.postid=notifications.postid 

AND notificationrecievers.notificationid=notifications.notid

AND notificationrecievers.recieverid=?

AND notifications.type=? 

AND friends.friendsid=victims.victimid

AND notificationrecievers.notificationid <=
(
   SELECT MAX(notid) FROM
   (
      SELECT n.notid FROM user u,notifications n,notificationrecievers nr WHERE
      nr.recieverid=? AND u.userid=n.senderid AND nr.notificationid=n.notid ORDER BY n.notid DESC
      LIMIT 50 OFFSET ?
   )a
)
AND notificationrecievers.notificationid >=
(
   SELECT MIN(notid) FROM
   (
      SELECT n.notid FROM user u,notifications n,notificationrecievers nr WHERE
      nr.recieverid=? AND u.userid=n.senderid AND nr.notificationid=n.notid ORDER BY n.notid DESC
      LIMIT 50 OFFSET ?
   )b
)
ORDER BY notifications.postid DESC;

UPDATE notificationrecievers 

SET notificationrecievers.status=1 

WHERE notificationrecievers.status=0
AND   notificationrecievers.recieverid=? 

AND

notificationrecievers.notificationid <=
(
     SELECT MAX(notid) FROM
     (
      SELECT n.notid FROM user u,notifications n,notificationrecievers nr WHERE
      nr.recieverid=? AND u.userid=n.senderid AND nr.notificationid=n.notid ORDER BY n.notid DESC
      LIMIT 50 OFFSET ?
     )e
)   

AND

notificationrecievers.notificationid >=
(
     SELECT min(notid) FROM
     (
      SELECT n.notid FROM user u,notifications n,notificationrecievers nr WHERE
      nr.recieverid=? AND u.userid=n.senderid AND nr.notificationid=n.notid ORDER BY n.notid DESC
      LIMIT 50 OFFSET ?
     )g
);

';
EXECUTE STMT USING @uid,@post,@uid,@rangee,@uid,@rangee,@uid,@uid,@rangee,@uid,@rangee;
```

When I run this query in the procedure it gives me syntax error.But when I use it directly by giving hard coded values in place of `?` than it works fine.Why is this happening? `puserid` and `plimit` are the parameters which i pass to this procedure.

This is the error:

```
Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';

UPDATE 
notificationrecievers 
SET notificationrecievers.st' at line 25
```

Comment: Check your version of MySQL... using parameters for LIMIT or OFFSET wasn't allowed until version 5.5.6.

Comment: the parameters work fine in other queries thats not the problem